# ncurses - printw() doesn't work with long strings (C)

Tags: c, ncurses

I'm trying to print a long string with `printw()` but it only print some chars. It's like this function only allow a maximum numbers of chars to print.

Here's a part of my code:

```
 ...
 move(3,0);
 printw(result_2);
 sleep(1);
 ...
```

`result_2` has a very long string and I know that it has the long string correctly.

The string that I'm trying to print is all the information about a txt file.

I tried with another functions like addstr() but I had the same problem. Is there any way to print long strings with `ncurses`?

This is what I have in my string:

```
user: asdasdasd
user: holaaaa
user: asdsad
user: aw22
user: 2
user: 2
user: 2
user: 2
user: 22
user: 2
user: 2
user: 2
user: asdasd
user: holaaa
user: porfa
user: si
user: suuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu
user: no
user: no
user: lel
user: lkajsdkjasdkjasdkjasd
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think it stops at the first `\n` it encounters... (I've had this problem once and as far as I remember it was that.)

Comment: @Jean-MarcZimmer I have multiples `\n` in the text file and I had no problems with it...

Comment: Well I don't know then. Sorry !

Comment: (Not directly related to your question, but I hope `result_2` doesn't have any percent signs in it. It's better to avoid that risk and `printw("%s", result_2)`.)

Comment: Don't know the answer, but: How much does it print / where does it cut it off? Does it vary whether you have one long string (no `\n`s)? Is your string long-enough to start scrolling the display (or... dredging my long-ago knowledge of curses.. to go beyond any window you may have defined, or the end of the screen? Could curses be deciding "it won't fit" and so doesn't display it?

Comment: There's no [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and none of the comments elicited useful information.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're probably hitting the bottom of the screen. Ncurses will not scroll (or allow the terminal to scroll) unless you've called:

```
scrollok(stdscr, TRUE);
```

So probably the output reaches the bottom of the window and stops there.

You might also want to take a look at the curses function `idlok`.

However, that might not provide what you are really looking for. Ncurses does not maintain a scroll buffer; it only stores what is actually being displayed on the screen. If you want to implement a CLI app which is capable of scrolling long texts, you'll have to implement the scrolling logic yourself, or use one of the widget libraries implemented on top of ncurses (such as [CDK](https://invisible-island.net/cdk/cdk.html)).

Comment: Id doesn't work :(. The output text doesn't reach the bottom of the windows anytime. When it stops displaying the information I can see the ^A character as the last one ...

Comment: @HessianMad If you still have problems, please [edit] your question to answer the questions from comments and add an [MCVE]. Without such details, people will just be guessing.

Comment: I found the problem. It wasn't about `ncurses`. Was about my `C` implementation.

Comment: @hessianMad: then you should probably delete the question.